# Gave Loan After Due Date on a Contract. Is the contract still enforceable?

Tags: contract-law, business, civil, loan

I loaned someone a sum of money on a contract that was dated on January 5th by both parties. The contract, however states the loan was to be sent on January 2nd and the money was sent on January 5th. Is this contract still enforceable?

Additionally, the contract states that the borrower must pay all lawyer fees. How likely is it that that will be successfully enforced?

Comment: What do you mean by loan sent on the 2nd of January and money sent on the 5th?

Answer (score 1):

Just because things don't go exactly to plan doesn't invalidate a contract.

Even if there was some material consequence from late money transfer then the contract doesn't vanish into thin air either.  If a contract exists, which it appears it did, then it can be disputed but not erased from history.  That's the whole purpose of a contracts and contract law, to manage the relationship between parties.